# Why are there grids on every entity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

Hey guys. There have been these grid like things that show up on every entity. Idk why and it's really bothering my work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You have activated a F3 command: <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>. It shows the hitboxes of entities. To disable it, press <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> again(or add the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key if it doesn't work).

> F3+B : Toggle visibility of hitboxes of entities. It also shows which direction entities are looking in using a blue line.

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Debug_screen

Comment: Thanks man. I forgot about that. I didn't know what it meant! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Lilkxdude4101 No problem! Remember you can check the check mark below the ratings to mark the answer as accepted.